# Array 2 method random generated number

Tags: c#

For a part of a program i need the following 2 methods.

The first method listed will generated a random number.
where the 2nd method will "call" this method to fill the array.

The array has a max. number of elements defefined on 100 (and all the random generated numbers should be between 1-100).

The problem is i never get random numbers generated. (either i get 100 x the same value, 3 random numbers divided over the 100 max. elements of the array,  or the same value 100 times all over again).

The problem should be in the first method, but i cannot seem to figure out the problem.
Been staring at this for quite some time now...

The problem should be with the return, cause it DOES create random generated numbers. But how do i return the generated value every time? (the int method has to be called with the 3 parameters).

```
        private int ValidNumber(int[] T, int X, int Range)
    {
        for (byte I = 0; I < T.Lenght; I++)
        {
            Random RndInt = new Random();
            X = RndInt.Next(1, Range+1);
        }
        return X; 

    }/*ValidNumber*/


  public void FillArray(int[] T, int Range)
    {
        for (byte I = 0; I < T.Length; I++)
        {
            T[I] = ValidNumber(T, I, Range);
        }

    }/*FillArray*/
```

Console code:

```
public void ExecuteProgram()
    {
        ClsBereken Ber = new ClsBereken();

        //const byte Range = 100;
        const int Max = 100;
        int[] T = new int[Max];

        Ber.FillArray(T, Max);
        DisplayArray(T);

    }/*ExecuteProgram*/

    private void DisplayArray(int[] T)
    {
        for (byte i = 0; i < T.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("{0,4} ", T[i]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }/*DisplayArray*/
```

Any help alot appreciated.
Kind Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-use the `Random` instance. **NOTE** I've edited this to show passing the `Random` instance down, but I'm really not sure what `ValidNumber` is trying to do - it *looks* like it is juts burning up CPU cycles? I would suggest you can remove `ValidNumber` completely (and just use the next value from the `Random` in `FillArray`), but presumably you are trying to do *something* here - I'm just not sure what!

```
private int ValidNumber(int[] T, int X, int Range, Random random)
{
    for (byte I = 0; I < T.Lenght; I++)
    {
        X = random.Next(1, Range+1);
    }
    return X; 

}/*ValidNumber*/


public void FillArray(int[] T, int Range)
{
    Random random = new Random();
    for (byte I = 0; I < T.Length; I++)
    {
        T[I] = ValidNumber(T, I, Range, random);
    }

}/*FillArray*/
```

When you create a `Random`, it is "seeded" using the system clock, but this is rounded heavily. If you create lots of `Random` in a tight loop, they all get the same "seed", so they all create the same next number.

If necessary you could move the `Random` further out (if you have other loops), or make it `static` (but if you do that you need to worry about synchronization too).

Comment: Marc, he _has_ to move the Random instance further out. Look at the code, only the last value of this loop is used.

Comment: I see, so something like this should solve the "seeding"?
Random RndInt = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks);

Although my array keeps creating 100 x of the same random number.

Comment: @Nerathas: DateTime.Ticks is still way too slow, and allready used by the default ctor in your code. Re-use the Random object.

Comment: Hello, cheers for the replies.
But re-use how exactly? Still a bit puzzled about the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are reinitializing rndint over and over.

take the line:

```
Random RndInt = new Random();
```

and move it in front of the loop and see if that fixes it.

When you initialize a random object, it is assigned a seed (probably based on the time), and that seed is used to generate a series of seemingly random values.  However, if you plug in the same seed to two random objects, you will get the same series of random numbers.

So, what is happening in your code is you are initializing a new random object with a seed, and then asking for the first random number in its series.  Then, you are initializing another random object (even though it is assigned to the same name, it is a new object) and it is getting the same seed, and you are again asking for the first random number in the series.  So naturally, you are getting the same random number over and over.

Answer (score 0):

You are continuously creating an new Random object. I'm afraid this is seeded (randomized) by the timestamp of creation. Since this is really fast and happens multiple times, the seed is the same, and so is the result of the call `RndInt.Next(1, Range+1);`.

By the way, even though not incorrect, it's not a common practice in c#.net to start with a capital letter on names of local variables and parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Any random number generation algorithm* is not *truly* random; it is simply a deterministic algorithm that has been specifically designed to output numbers that resemble randomness. (See [Pseudorandom number generator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_number_generator).) Since the algorithm is deterministic, its output is completely dependent upon a starting "seed" value.

The `Random` class in .NET has two constructors: one which takes an integer seed, and another which takes no parameters. This one bases its seed off the current time.

From this information perhaps you can guess why creating a new `Random` instance for every value in your array results in the entire array being filled with the same number: every time you construct a `Random` object **within a very small time frame**, it will have the same seed value, which means it will generate identical output to another `Random` object constructed within the same time frame.

As Marc Gravell has already indicated, you should be using only a single `Random` instance to generate a sequence of random numbers.

*Well, *almost* any. I believe there are hardware implementations of random number generators that factor in random noise (taken from the surrounding environment) and may therefore be considered "truly" random. Whether you believe *these* are **actually** random 
depends on your personal definition of "random" and whether or not you believe that we live in a deterministic universe.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass Random() a seed but if you send it the same seed number you will get the same results. The way you are using it

```
Random rnd = new Random();
```

Is using an auto-generated seed based on time. But you may not get seemingly random results if you don't at least sleep for a second. (Source http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random(VS.71).aspx)

As everyone has mentioned here already your biggest issue is the fact you keep recreating the random object each iteration.